# Sonar issue for calling static method from non static method

Tags: java, sonarqube

I am getting sonar issue for accessing static method from a non static method. I am not sure how to resolve this issue. Application context is static member. what is the best way to solve the sonar issue without affecting the business flow. I dont want to create it as non static member as it may side efftect.

```java
public class ApplicationContextHolder implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext>, ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return applicationContext ;
    }

    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) throws BeansException {
        applicationContext = (ConfigurableApplicationContext) context;
    }

    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext context) {
        applicationContext = context;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, if the only thing `setApplicationContext` is doing, is to set a `static` field, then the `setApplicationContext` method could be `static` as well.

Comment: If `ApplicationContextHolder` is a singleton then there's no reason to have `applicationContext` be static. Without knowing anything about your app it seems like there could be side effects as shown.

Comment: This is a Spring anti-pattern.

Comment: This is an anti-pattern in any multithreaded application.  The rule just tells you that this will cause trouble down the line as the operation is not guaranteed to be thread-safe. It also generously suggests using `synchronized static` methods.

Comment: It's not about threadsafety, it's about subverting the DI containers control. Mark Seeman has posted about this, just can't find it now.

Comment: @NathanHughes I think I found the [thread-by-Mark-Seeman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1629404/2915738) ?